# pygame sprites not rendering or updating

Tags: animation, pygame, render, collision, sprite

What works:

1) the ship and background load without hitch.
2) ship movement is functioning
3) I was able to keep the ship from being able to exit the field of view
4) the program creates pixels(to emulate bullets) at the KEYDOWN event of K_SPACEBAR

What I need help with:

1)Despite my best efforts after creating the "bullets" the sprites wont animate
2) The sprites intended to represent debris won't even create let alone animate
3) of course this means I can't even test my unit collision betwen bullets and debris
4) don't know how to begin tackling debris (sprite) detection with the ship
5) For some reason the bullet sprites render to the left of the ship. Not sure where/how to manipulate their x value

Code as it stands:
I've left notes all over the place to help explain my madness

```
bif="bg.jpg"
ship = "spaceship.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()
yellow=(255,255,51)
green=(50,190,50)

difficulty = 10
i=0
debris_list=pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list=pygame.sprite.Group()


class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#makes squares

    def __init__(self, color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface ([7,7])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #bullet creation

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image= pygame.Surface([7,7])
        self.image.fill(yellow)
        self.rect= self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):    #sprite movement
        if bullet:
            self.rect.y-=5
        if debris:
            self.rect.y+=5

class debris(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #debris creation

    def __init__(self,color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image= pygame.Surface([15,15])
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect= self.image.get_rect()






window =pygame.display.set_caption("Space Explorer")
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
speed=250
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32)
x,y =0,0
movex,movey= 0,0
background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert() # puts background on screen
ship_pos=pygame.image.load(ship).convert_alpha() #loads player ship

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: #escape functionality
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:  #ship movement
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif     event.key ==K_UP:
            movey=-1
            elif event.key ==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
            elif event.key == K_a:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key == K_d:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key ==K_w:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key ==K_s:
                movey=+1
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key ==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key ==K_DOWN:
                movey=0
            elif event.key == K_a:
                movex=0
            elif event.key == K_d:
                movex=0
            elif event.key ==K_w:
                movey=0
            elif event.key ==K_s:
                movey=0

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:#player input bullet creation:
            if event.key==K_SPACE:
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet.rect.x=x
                bullet.rect.y=y
                bullet_list.add(bullet)

        #hit tracking and score
        #no collision detection for debris and ship yet.
        for bullet in bullet_list: 
            debris_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet,debris_list,True)
            for debris in debris_hit_list:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                score+1
                print score
            if bullet.rect.y<10:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)#stop tracking rogue bullets

     #debris spawn location and rate
     #every 10 iterations "debris" should spawn randomly on the x axis
     #and move downwards

        if i == difficulty:
            debris = Square(green)
            debris.rect.x= random.randrange(800)
            debris.rect.y=-700
            debris_list.add(debris)
            i=0
        i=i+1
        bullet_list.update()
        debris_list.update()    
    #keeps ship within screen
    if x >=680:
        x=680
    if x <= 5:
         x=5
    if y >=500:
        y= 500
    if y <=5:
        y=5
    x+=movex
    y+=movey
    bullet_list.draw(screen)
    debris_list.draw(screen)


    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(ship_pos,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for my english)

1) In Bullet.update() you use

```py
    if bullet: 
        self.rect.y-=5
    if debris:
        self.rect.y+=5
```

But the objects bullet and debris are

A: Not defined (at the beginning of the code)

B: return false  (I think)

But if they would both return true the bullet stays in the same place.

2) The debris class is never used (you use the rect class)

The debris y = -700 what is ABOVE the screen

3) I think the coliding works

4)  Define a Ship_Rect and do

```py
for d in debris_list:
    if Ship_Rect.colliderect(d.rect):
        //Stuff to do when ship collides debris
```

5) The X and Y of an object are in the top left corner you should do:

```py
    bullet.rect.x= x + (Ship_Rect.heigth/2)
    bullet.rect.y= y + (Ship_Rect.length/2)
```